# How to mimic refresh behaviour in javascript?

Tags: javascript

After the user uploads 2 images in browser I do some processing on the server and then attach the result on the web again. It works well, but in order to do it again the user has to refresh the page, otherwise the server crashes.
 How could I modify this code to make it work like so: after the user uploads 2 pictures and gets the result, if the user chooses to change one or both of the initial pictures the new result is displayed again on the webpage?

```
const formData = new FormData();
$('#resbtn').hide();
$(".uploadbuttons").on("change", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.type !== "file") {
        return;
    }
    if (!tgt.files || !tgt.files[0]) {
        return;
    }
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const idx = tgt.id.replace("picture", "");
    formData.append(`image${idx}`, tgt.files[0]); // append image with index idx
    reader.onload = async function(e) {
        const image = `<img src="${e.target.result}" style="width:20vw;height:auto;" id="image${idx}-morph">`;
        $("#appendimg" + idx).html(image);
        if ($(".uploadbuttons").find("img").length === 2) {
            await fetch('/saveImage', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            }).then(function(res) {
                // console.log(res.json());
            }).then(function(data) {
                // console.log(data);
            });

            await fetch('/processImg', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            }).then(async function(res) {
                // console.log(res.json());
                await res.text().then(function(img) {
                    $('#resbtn').show(500);
                    $('#resbtn').on('click', function() {
                        const image = `<img src="${img}" style="width:20vw;height:auto;">`;
                        $("#appendResult").html(image);
                    });
                });
            }).then(function(data) {
                // console.log(data);
            });
        }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(tgt.files[0]);
});
```

The server posts are the following:

```
//upload images to server
app.post('/saveImage', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Both images were uploaded, algorithm starting...");
    const files = [req.files.image1, req.files.image2]; // files from request
    const fileNames = [req.files.image1.name, req.files.image2.name];
    const paths = [__dirname + '/uploads/' + fileNames[0], __dirname + '/uploads/' + fileNames[1]];
    //upload images to folder
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        files[i].mv(paths[i], (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.end(JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: err }));
                return;
            }
            res.end(JSON.stringify({ status: 'images were successfully saved to the server'}));
        });
    }
});

app.post('/processImg',async function (req, res) {
    const img1Name = req.files.image1.name;
    const img2Name = req.files.image2.name;
    const { outputImg1, outputImg2 } = await processImages(img1Name, img2Name);
    await facialDetection(outputImg1, outputImg2);
    setTimeout(function() {
        const image64 = base64_encode(`${__dirname}\\uploads\\MorphedFace.jpg`);
        removeDir(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')); //clean folder
        res.send(image64)}, 5000); // wait 5s
});
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="uploadbuttons">
    <form>
        <input type="file" id="picture1">
        <div id="appendimg1"></div>
    </form>
    <form>
        <input type="file" id="picture2">
        <div id="appendimg2"></div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="getResult">
    <button id="resbtn">Show result</button>
    <div id="appendResult"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The error I get in the server is the following (the image path does not update before the new call to post):

```
var name1 = img1Name.split('.')[0]; //get name w/o extension
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

Comment: You can use `location.reload()`. But `otherwise the server crashes.` sounds more like a priority job to me..

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new FormData object every time, otherwise you are just adding more items at the same name-index and your server isn't ready to accept such format:

```js
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append("foo", "bar");
fd.append("foo", "baz");
new Response( fd ).text().then( console.log );
```

So move `const formData = new FormData();` inside the `onchange` handler.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, it is a great starting point for my issue. For my current approach I get another error while trying to save the images because it overrides the formData every time I upload a picture. I think I have to do a case for each input button and then check to see if there are 2 images in the whole div..